# How to manage hardware resources efficiently in a cloud gaming service?

Tags: windows, virtualization, resource-management, gameserver

I am creating this small cloud gaming service (GeforceNow wannabe) which is powered by windows 10 Pro and VMWware. All other aspect of it is taken care of, Like streaming and data compression and etc. On the other side i have like 50 indie game which are not resource heavy with an average of 1GB of graphic, 4GB RAM and average of 5GB Storage per game. There is another section with 20 AAA games and very resource heavy like 4GB GPU, 12GB RAM and 50GB Storage per game and the category of games are growing (slowly but planning for 100 indie and 50 AAA in mid 2021). Also i am expecting 100000 total users with ~2000 playing concurrently

How can i manage the installation of this games to save the maximum amount of GPU and CPU power and SSD storage? Should i dedicate a server capable of more users with all indie games and couple bigger servers with each one contain all AAA's? Or is there a way to put all of those in one server and just manage user states and progress? How the real and working cloud gaming services manage this?

I was thinking about moving to docker from VMWare to use hardware more dynamically but i think running heavy games in docker and steaming to browser is not good for quality and performance sake. Plus tons of optimiztions and configurations are necessary in docker.

Comment: I really like to know what is wrong with my question so i can improve it.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit of an unorthodox setup, but if you want to maximise space utilisation of multiple instances of the same image, you'd need to move over to VMware Horizon or some other VDI solution, where you can have a base images for the OS, as well as application images for the different apps the users want to run. Horizon can then combine the base OS image with the required application storage and user storage, and create a temporary VM with the required applications at login time, that then gets destroyed at logoff so that you're only storing the OS once even though you might have hundreds of clients.

Keep in mind that what you're describing also sounds like absolute hell when it comes to licensing, and you'd probably need some sort of service provider licencing arrangement with at least Microsoft for the Windows 10 instances you're running.

Comment: This is a interesting solution. I was thinking about working with snapshots but it lowers the performance. About the windows pro edition i had to choose this version because of the performance and gaming optimizations. I could go with linux like what google did with Stadia but windows is easier to work with for gamers.

Comment: Actually i was thinking about using a VDI solution for a long time but accessing the server with a custom client is my issue in this matter.

Comment: Snapshots are a definite no-go in any production environment, they lower performance immensely. There are of course application virtualisation technologies as well that could be used to just virtualize the application.